# Static src="" but dynamic contnent on iframe

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

i am looking for a method to have a static iframe src but a dynamic contnet of iframe, i was thinking about switch the object of the search. Is there any php command that can do it?Is this a good way to do it?
Thanks in advice, have a good day :).

Comment: Manipulating an iframe's contents without modifying the `src` attribute sounds like a Javascript issue to me, not a PHP problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the file which one you want to display via $_GET

***page.php?file=document.pdf***

```
if(isset($GET['file'])):
  ?>
  <iframe src="static/path/<?php echo $_GET['file'];?>"  />
  <?php
  else:
  ?>
  <h1>Bitte Datei auswählen!</h1>
  <?php
endif;
```

But please be aware of security and take measures to prevent harm to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic content you can do in jQuery using ajax:
Try something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function getPage(id) {
    $('#output').html('<img src="LoaderIcon.gif" />');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "get_page.php",
        data:'id='+id,
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){$('#output').html(data);}
    });
}
</script>
```